# Duplication of data in communication between components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, components, state-management

I have two dropdwown(select in HTML) and I need to send the value of both when selected and send request.

```
<app-dropdown-segment></app-dropdown-segment>
<div>receiving data from the drop-segment: {{receivesSegment}}</div>

<app-dropdown-lever></app-dropdown-lever>
<div>receiving data from the drop-lever: {{receivesLever}}</div>
```

But when I select an option it reflects the options chosen in the two interpolations:

**Dropdown-segment and dropdown-lever**

[image: drop segment and drop lever*]

I'm doing the communication between the components with behaviorSubject

**Dropdown Segment component**

```
  chooseSegment(e){
    this.segmentSelected = e.target.value
    this.dropDownService.emitSegmentSelected<string>(this.segmentSelected)
  }
```

**dropdown.service.ts**

```
export class DropDownService {

    public _subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

    emitSegmentSelected<T>(dataSegment: T){
      this._subject.next(dataSegment)
    }

    emitLeverSelected<T>(dataLeaver: T){
      this._subject.next(dataLeaver)
    }

    onSegmentSelected <T>(): Observable<T>{
      return this._subject.asObservable();
  }

    onLeverSelected <T>(): Observable<T>{
    return this._subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Parent component that receives data from the two dropdowns:

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.dropDownService.onSegmentSelected<string>().subscribe(
        dataSegment =>{
          this.receivesSegment = dataSegment;
        })
    
    this.dropDownService.onLeverSelected<string>().subscribe(
      dataLever =>{
        this.receivesLever = dataLever;
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot have 1 subject for both dropdowns. With this approach create 2 subjects for each data type

Comment: it is not 'duplication'. subject holds only one value and such as your dropdowns both subscribe to 1 source - they would get 1 value. I assume when you would select Lever - upper segment would also display lever

Comment: thanks! Can you tell me what is the best way to reuse just a dropdown on several components? any article? thanks @andriishupta

Comment: Use component's `@Input` and `@Output` directives to get best data sharing options between components
[docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: np! I would suggest following Input-Output(as @Abhijit mentioned), but it would be better to not overengineer stuff and use some lib for such components: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview and https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns are both good, depends on what you want to use as for design: Material or Bootstrap. Also, you can create a custom design with material https://material.angular.io/guide/theming